# Range a Number 0 to 100 from the User

Tags: java

I'm new to programming, and one of my assignments is making a code for a number ranging from 0 to 100; if a number is negative, I have to convert the negative to positive. I tried many ways to solve this problem but couldn't. If anyone can explain how to solve this problem, that would be great.

```
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 to 100: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int range = input.nextInt();
    
    // Display the user result 
    if (user1 > range) 
        System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); 
    else if (user1 > range) 
        System.out.println("An incorrect number was entered"); 
    else 
    {
    System.out.print("The number range " + range + " needs to be positive "); 
    System.out.print(range * -1); // If the number is negative convert to positive
    }
        
}
```

Comment: __Tip__: use absolute value instead of using tricky times -1's

Comment: You need to learn [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com).  Hint: what is the obvious error in this:  `if (user1 > range) System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); else if (user1 > range) ...` ?

Comment: [`Math.abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int))

Comment: In fact, `i * -1` is NOT guaranteed to flip the sign of `i`.  Try it with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your missing on:

your inaccurate naming of the "range" variable is most possibly confusing you

I think you meant user1 to be the user input rather than the "range" variable. Here, it teaches you a very important lesson that all programmers will learn at some time: **Name your variables so that you can understand them**

for a more descriptive variable name, I will rename user1 to user_input

```
int user_input = input.nextInt();
```

which modifies your code to

```
    if (user_input > range) {
        System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); 
    }
    else if (user_input > range) {
        System.out.println("An incorrect number was entered"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("The number range " + user_input + " needs to be positive "); 
        System.out.print(user_input * -1); // If the number is negative convert to positive
    }
```

*I also added some brackets for readability and proper formatting*

moving on from this, it seems that what you meant by range here is the 0 and 100 range that the problem sets which gives

```
    if (user_input > 0) {
        System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); 
    }
    else if (user_input > 100) {
        System.out.println("An incorrect number was entered"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("The number range " + user_input + " needs to be positive "); 
        System.out.print(user_input * -1); // If the number is negative convert to positive
    }
```

finally We have a working, nice looking code.

For the last touch I recommend using abs to change signs for better understanding. Which modifies to

```
        if (user_input > 0) {
            System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); 
        }
        else if (user_input > 100) {
            System.out.println("An incorrect number was entered"); 
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("The number range " + user_input + " needs to be positive "); 
            System.out.print(Math.abs(user_input)); // If the number is negative convert to positive
        }
```

Now we are done :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd re-write that as:

```
int minInclusive = 0;
int maxInclusive = 100;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a number between " + minInclusive + " and " + maxInclusive + " inclusive: ");    
int number = Math.abs(input.nextInt()); // number is now POSITIVE    
if (number >= minInclusive && number <= maxInclusive) {  // COMPOUND BOOLEAN EXPRESSION!
    System.out.println("A correct number was entered "); 
}
else {
    System.out.println("An incorrect number was entered"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is negative then simply negate the value

```
if(range < 0) {
  range = -range;
}
```